# Session isn't working in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on one code of login and user profile but I am facing problem with session. I want to do when user login through Login.php then it goes to User.php. But when I open this page in a new tab then it goes to Login.php and again asks for Login. Can anyone tell me where I am wrong? My code is below.

Login.Php

```
<?php 
session_start();
// check if session set.
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $url=SITE_URL.'User.php';
   (header("Location: $url"));
}
?>

<?php 
include("dbconfig.php");
include('class/userClass.php');
$userClass = new userClass();

$errorMsgLogin='';
if (!empty($_POST['loginSubmit'])) 
{
$usernameEmail=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
 if(strlen(trim($usernameEmail))>1 && strlen(trim($password))>1 )
   {
    $id=$userClass->userLogin($usernameEmail,$password);
    if($id)
    {
        $url=SITE_URL.'User.php';
        header("Location: $url");
    }
    else
    {
        $errorMsgLogin="Please check login details.";
    }
   }
}


?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form id="contact-form" method="post">
            <div class="login-controls">
                <div class="form-input">
                    <input type="text" class="txt-box"  name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-input">
                    <input type="password" class="txt-box" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                </div>
<div class="errorMsg"><?php echo $errorMsgLogin; ?></div>
                <div class="main-bg">
                    <input type="submit"  name="loginSubmit" id="submit" class="btn " value="Login">
                </div>
<div class="check-box">
                    <a href="ForgotPassword.php">Forgot your Password ?</a>
                </div>


</form>
</br></br>
</body>
</html>
```

User.php

```
 <?php
    session_start();

    // check if session set.
    if(!isset($_SESSION['id']) || empty($_SESSION['id'])) {
        $url=SITE_URL.'Login.php';
        die(header("Location: $url"));
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    $session_id=$_SESSION['id'];
    include('class/userClass.php');
    $userClass = new userClass();
    include('dbconfig.php');
    $userDetails=$userClass->userDetails($session_id);
    ?>

         <!doctype html>
            <html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
          ------------something-----
                </body>
            </html>
```

dbconfig.php

```
<?php
session_start();
/* DATABASE CONFIGURATION */
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'XXXXXX');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'XX2');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'Xxxx');
define("SITE_URL", "http://try1234.com"); // Eg. http://yourwebsite.com


function getDB() 
{
    $dbhost=DB_SERVER;
    $dbuser=DB_USERNAME;
    $dbpass=DB_PASSWORD;
    $dbname=DB_DATABASE;
    try {
    $dbConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass); 
    $dbConnection->exec("set names utf8");
    $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbConnection;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

}
?>
```

userClass.php

```
<?php
    class userClass
    {
         /* User Login */
         public function userLogin($usernameEmail,$password)
         {

              $db = getDB();
              $hash_password= hash('sha256', $password);
              $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM profile WHERE  username=:usernameEmail  AND  pass=:hash_password");  
              $stmt->bindParam("usernameEmail", $usernameEmail,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
              $stmt->bindParam("hash_password", $hash_password,PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
              $stmt->execute();
              $count=$stmt->rowCount();
              $data=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
              $db = null;
              if($count)
              {
                    $_SESSION['id']=$data->id;
                    return true;
              }
              else
              {
                   return false;
              }    
         }

         /* User Details */
         public function userDetails($id)
         {
            try{
              $db = getDB();
              $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT email,username,Pname, Mobile FROM profile WHERE id=:id");  
              $stmt->bindParam("id", $id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
              $stmt->execute();
              $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
              return $data;
             }
             catch(PDOException $e) {
              echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
              }

         }


    }

?>
```

Comment: You need to `session_start();` on every single page you plan to use sessions. That's why it isn't working, because you haven't started the session on `session.php`.

Comment: At the top of every single page that uses it :-) (`<?php session_start();`)

Comment: @Darren thank for reply ..i will try

Comment: @Darren its working thank for support

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, if you want to use sessions on any page, you will **always** need to start the session.

This is usually done as the very first thing on each of those pages:

```
<?php
session_start();

//.....the rest of your code.
```

---

Evidentally, you will need to start it on your `session.php` page for it to work.

It's also worth noting that your `session.php` logic is a bit redundant. You'd be better off doing something similar to:

```
<?php
session_start();

// check if session set.
if(!isset($_SESSION['id']) || empty($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $url=SITE_URL.'Login.php';
    die(header("Location: $url"));
}
// otherwise continue.
include('class/userClass.php');
$userClass = new userClass();

//.... the rest of your code.
```

<sup>*The above removes redundant/recursive checks if the session is present &  allows proper code "flow".*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you know you're going to need session availability on each page, you can edit your `php.ini` and add `session.auto_start = 1`, or you can do as the commenter above suggested and add `session_start();` in each of your files (or use a base `include` containing `session_start();`)

Comment: i am trying Darren suggestion but it still not solve and i edited my code maybe i am something wrong so suggest me

Comment: Have you made absolutely certain that 1) cookies are enabled and 2) that there is absolutely nothing displaying to the browser before the `session_start()` call?

Comment: i am not getting you .. i try  above code which i already edited but still same issue going

Comment: The above code looks fine, but are you sure that nothing else is being sent to the browser before you call `session_start()`.  There are very few reasons for sessions to not work, and I'm trying to help you investigate.